# Redirect when submit Feedback form

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I have made a Feedback Form in comments entity, Each node has multi file fields, I'm looking to force the users to submit the form & give their feedback after that redirect them to file download when click submit button, I'm using Views & Custom Formatters and I made the feedback form displays in Colorbox popup to keep them on the same page

feedback URL "node/%/feedback"

is there any function that can help me ? I'm using Drupal 7

Comment: I'ts a drupal 7 form made with form API, or it's just HTML?

Comment: Hi ! it's drupal 7 form API ! is there any simple way to do it ?? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a submit function if you dont have and set the url you want redirect in $form_state['redirect'].

```
function my_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/10';
}
```

More information [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1975230).

Comment: Please, just something! How can I make the URL change automatically, Change it with file URL " audio/[file:name]?download " ?

Comment: First, if your URL is node/%/feedback you must change it to node/%node/feedback to ler drupal knows that URL contains q node id, and clear caches. Then in form submit you can declare a variable like This: $node = menu_get_object(); (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7.x). Now you have the node object in a variable, and you can inspect his value with dpm function from devel module (https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) in order to know where is your audio file name. I doesnt have my computer to test it correctly but it should works.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Omar but let's say it's hard for me to do it because of my coding level :p, please is it possible for you to help me with that, send you the site & SQL file, please

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom submit handlers for your form.

After submitting the first form, you should make a redirect tour feedback form and after submitting the comment form you should make a redirect to the files page.

See [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/717740) for further information.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you so much, this is so helpful but my problem is I'm not so good in codes so I don't know how to do it & what should I change ... is there any simple way thank you